# Linear regression analysis in R

Tags: raster, r, grids-graticules, analysis, regression

I would like to conduct a simple linear regression analysis in R with two grids. So I have two Raster images of the same region and I need to do a regression analysis, but I struggle with doing that. This is what I have tried:

```
library(raster)

timestats <- brick("trend_timestats.tif")
force <- brick("versuch1.tif")

regression <-lm(timestats ~ force)
```

I often struggle with rather basic functions in R, do you know any good tutorials for beginners?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this seems to be a duplicate of the following Stack Overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48194502/linear-regression-between-two-raster-images-in-r

Comment: We can't do this without more information about your data. How many layers are in those bricks? What is that `setwd("...")` doing there? What do those plots look like? Are those plots relevant? A good question - ie one that is likely to get answered - should either have code that other people can run by cut and paste, or give *lots* of information about the data you are working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48213167/635245) (as Erik pointed out) for how to do this with `raster`. Here I show something similar with `terra`

When asking an R question, always include some example data:

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra")) 
s
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 77, 101, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#red-grn-blue: 1, 2, 3 
#names       : red, green, blue 
#min values  :   0,     0,    0 
#max values  : 255,   255,  255
```

Solution for a model regressing `red` with `green`

```
m <- lm(red~green, data=as.data.frame(s))
```

And you could make a spatial prediction like this

```
 p <- predict(s, m)
 # residuals
 error <- s$red - p
 plot(error)
```

[image: residuals]

If you have separate `SpatRaster`s `x` and `y` first combine them into a single `SpatRaster`

```
x <- s[[1]]
y <- s[[2]]
xy <- c(x, y)
m <- lm(red~green, data=as.data.frame(xy))
```

If the rasters are very large, you can take a regular (better than random) sample

```
d <- data.frame(spatSample(s, 10000, "regular"))
m <- lm(red~green, data=d)
summary(m)
#Call:
#lm(formula = red ~ green, data = d)
#
#Residuals:
#    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#-16.064  -2.211   1.789   2.502  12.243 
#
#Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept) -6.4633126  0.1422080  -45.45   <2e-16 ***
#green        1.0183308  0.0007138 1426.73   <2e-16 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 4.601 on 7774 degrees of freedom
#  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
#Multiple R-squared:  0.9962,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9962 
#F-statistic: 2.036e+06 on 1 and 7774 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

For tutorials see https://rspatial.org which has chapters on spatial regression. These may be especially important if your goal is inference you need to consider the problem of coefficient estimation and inflation of p-values due to spatial autocorrelation (pseudo-replication).

For *local regression*, that is, a regression model for each grid cell (pixel), you can do use `app`. Here I show that using linear algebra for speed (much faster than calling `lm`)

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   

## the 1 is to get a slope. 
## 1:nlyrs(s) is the independent variable    
X <- cbind(1, 1:nlyr(s))

## pre-computing constant part of least squares
invXtX <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X)

## [2] is to just get the slope
quickfun <- function(y) (invXtX %*% y)[2]
slope <- app(s, quickfun) 
plot(slope)
```

[image: local regression]

With `lm` you can do

```
time <- 1:nlyr(s)
fun <- function(x) { lm(x ~ time)$coefficients[2] }
slp <- app(s, fun)
```